# Telerik Angular Kendo Upload control - respond to row click

Tags: kendo-angular-ui

using kendoFileSelectFileTemplate,

would like to have some Angular TypeScript code run when the user clicks in the whitespace in the `<li>` elements rendered by the kendo-upload control.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ng-template kendoFileSelectFileTemplate let-files let-state="state">
            <div (click)="onClick()">Name: {{files[0].name}} Size: {{files[0].size}} bytes</div>
</ng-template>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5z55d